# How to redirect www.facebook.com to localhost using bind in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04

How to redirect `www.facebook.com` to localhost using bind?

Answer (score 1):

Set up a authorative zone for facebook.com in bind, and set 127.0.0.1 as the A record:

```
$TTL 86400

@       IN      SOA     ns1.facebook.com.      admin.example.com. (
                        2017122701  ; serial number YYMMDDNN
                        28800           ; Refresh
                        7200            ; Retry
                        864000          ; Expire
                        86400           ; Min TTL
            )

                NS      ns1.facebook.com. 
                NS      ns2.facebook.com. 


$ORIGIN facebook.com.

facebook.com    IN  A   127.0.0.1 
wwww    IN  A   127.0.0.1
```

But it won't work. Facebook uses HSTS preloading in all major browsers, so browsers expect facebook to have a valid certificate, and be available over TLS.  You are probably unable to get a valid certificate for facebook.

If you want to block facebook, it's better to serve up a NXDOMAIN (No such domain) from Bind, and possibly block it using Squid or some other (transparent) proxy. Yes; A proxy can block a TLS connection based on hostname, but not based on content.

Furthermore, I have a feel this is a [X-Y question](http://xyproblem.info/). You'll probably get better answers if you say what you want to achieve.

Comment: Serving NXDOMAIN is easy with bind RPZ feature.